# Rails validation confirm true is not case sensitive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my `user.rb` model, I have a `email_confirm` field, so that users insert twice and validate the emails without typos

```
attr_accessor :email_confirmation
validates :email, confirmation: true, on: :create
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

But what happens is, if I insert an email with a capital letter, I get an validation error `"don't match"`. How do I confirm emails without case sensitive?

I'm using devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email validation, use a regex matcher:

```
validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
```

The `i` flag at the end of the regex sets case insensitivity. This validation also handles presence, since nil or a blank string would fail the above validation.

I recommend using Rubular for testing regexes: http://rubular.com/

**EDIT**

You can preprocess the attribute in a `before_validation` block:

```
before_validation :downcase_email

def downcase_email
  email_confirmation.try(:downcase!)
  email.try(:downcase!)
end
```

`try` is to prevent calling `downcase!` if email is nil.

Comment: I'm using Devise, it's already validating the format of the email

Comment: yup I ended up going with that approach :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom validator:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :email_confirmation

  validates :email, presence: true
  validate  :check_email_confirmation, if: :email_changed?

  private

  def check_email_confirmation
    if email.casecmp(email_confirmation.to_s).nonzero?
      errors.add(:email, "Emails don't match")
    end
  end

end
```

[`casecmp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-casecmp) is a case-insensitive string compare method. It does not work properly for fully-accented UTF-8 characters comparison but you don't need that in emails.

With this approach you don't have to change the input attributes in any way before validation. Also, I updated the validations so that `email` is a required attribute and that the confirmation check is done only when email changes.